# How to calculate similarity between categorical variables in collaborative filtering

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to build a recommender system using collaborative filtering.

1. I am having user-item dataset. I am unable to find similarity between similar user, since i cannot use  Euclidean / Cosine distance will not work here.
2. If i convert categorical variable into 0, 1 then will not able to calculate distance.
   Can you please suggest any recommendation algorithm in python which handles categorical data.

Comment: I think `Hamming Distance` is the metric you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

One good example to calculate distance between categorical features is `Hamming Distance` where we calculate the number of different instances.

On the other hand, you can still calculate Cosine Similarity for user-item data set.

As an example; 
user 1 buys item 1, item 2

user 2 buys item 2, item 3

Then, user vectors are;

user 1 = `[1, 1, 0]`

user 2 = `[0, 1, 1]`

And cosine similarity will be `0.5`

Same rules apply for items.

Answer (score 0):

Cosine similarity will handle the problem as a whole vector which includes all values of the variable. And may not give the answer for correlation. So when you received a good score from cosine similarity, it will not make sure they are also correlated.